# Allocating space for type within a function with malloc

Tags: c, malloc, typedef

I wrote a type

```
typedef
  struct matrix_s {
    int size;
    float *values;
  } matrix_t;
```

which I allocate in a function like this :

```
matrix_t *matrix;
genmat(mat, afloatarray, thesize);

//Function
void genmat(matrix_t *mat, float *_values, int _size) {
  mat = (matrix_t*) malloc(sizeof(matrix_t)); 
  mat->values = _values;
  mat->size = _size;
}
```

Shouldn't **matrix** and **mat** have the same pointer, because I pass a pointer and work with a pointer.

Comment: You shouldn't use identifiers beginning with an underscore; they're reserved in many contexts. You also should **not** cast the malloc return in C. You also should refer to the pointer to be allocated in the sizeof, as in `mat = malloc(sizeof (*mat))` as this *always* gets the type right. Last, but most important, you should read and understand the answers below :-)

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Comment: Should `genmat()` make a copy of the array pointed to by `_values`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the address of the pointer or return the newly allocated one.

```
matrix_t *genmat(float *_values, int _size)
{
    mat = malloc(sizeof(*mat)); 
    if (mat == NULL)
        return NULL;
    mat->values = _values;
    mat->size = _size;

    return mat;
}
```

And then

```
matrix_t *matrix;
matrix = genmat(afloatarray, thesize);
```

Or

```
void genmat(matrix_t **out, float *_values, int _size)
{
    *out = malloc(sizeof(**out)); 
    if (*out == NULL)
        return;
    (*out)->values = _values;
    (*out)->size = _size;
}
```

And then

```
matrix_t *matrix;
genmat(&matrix, afloatarray, thesize);
```

The reason for this is that in [c](/questions/tagged/c) parameters are always passed by value, and while you can modify the data the pointer points to, you cannot reassign the pointer inside the function because it will not affect the pointer of the caller function, since the parameter pointer and the pointer in the caller function have different addresses, although they both store the same address.

In the second of my sample solutions, the function takes the address of the pointer, and it can then modify the pointer from `main()` by dereferencing the double pointer.

Comment: That has done it, thanks. But why does matrix not hold the adress to the type?

Comment: @risingprogrammer I don't understand. Does my explanation at the end of the answer explain that?

Comment: I asked the question before you edited your answer. My bad

Comment: @risingprogrammer Also, I intentionally removed the `(matrix_t *)` cast since it's not needed and it just makes the code harder to read. And used the `sizeof` operator in a way that is more maintanable, since if you change the type of the `mat` parameter/variable you don't need to fix the `malloc()`, another thing that would make you need to fix the `malloc()` is the cast of course.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a pointer the pointer for matrix to `genmat()`.

This would look like:

```
matrix_t *matrix;
genmat(&mat, afloatarray, thesize);

//Function
void genmat(matrix_t **mat, float *_values, int _size) {
  *mat = malloc(sizeof(matrix_t)); 
  if (*mat == NULL) // Do not dereference a NULL poitner
      return;
  (*mat)->values = _values;
  (*mat)->size = _size;
}
```